# c# MVC Coding pattern for maintaining model properties

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, design-patterns

Right, so a) I'm not sure if this is the right forum for this question, I failed to find a better suggestion, and b) I couldn't find an answer to a question I can't believe I haven't asked before:

So if I have a model, standard form to fill in and it errors so I throw it back to the user, how do I, or how SHOULD I, structure the code to make sure all the supporting properties are constructed?

Example:

```
public ActionResult DoThing()
{
    var model = new DoThingModel();
    model.Things = ThingService.FetchThings();
    //Do Other Things
    return View(model);
}
```

The fairly standard GET action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoThing(DoThingModel model)
{
    var valid = ThingService.ValidateThing(model);
    if(!valid)
    {
        model.ValidationMessage = "Ohh no validation failed";
        model.valid = false;
        return View(model); //I have't rebuilt model.Things with ThingService.FetchThings()
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
}
```

So if the thing is valid redirect to the success page, but otherwise return the form (contained within the model) to the user with a validation message. Problem is my form page has things on it and I haven't populated the model with it.

Now, this is a very simple example and I could just pass back things in the form, or duplicate the line of code that populates it. But imagine I have a much more complicated model, with breadcrumbs, multiple properties that need populating. Code duplication = bad, so how SHOULD I be making sure the model has everything I need before passing it back? I thought about creating a service but it's a service with one function. I thought about using a constructor, but that doesn't play well with model binding. I thought about creating a DoThingModel.Init() that does all the work, but putting code like that inside a model class seems dirty. I played around with a private function in the Controller that filled in all the required properties, but this seems dirty again.

I feel like there should be a standard code pattern that goes => Create New Model => Make sure Model has everything that supports the page => return Model => validate Model => re-apply any properties => return Model => repeat until valid.

Like I said in the intro, this must be a standard thing somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: Your not going to find a 'standard' answer for this... it depends entirely on your model and application. As far as the options you presented, they seems reasonable. Not sure why you don't want to use a service because 'it only does one thing' - thats fine

Comment: Service does one thing does seem fine, except anyone looking at this after me has to open yet another class to see whats going on, it seems like an unnecessary complication. But I will say it does seem like the cleanest approach.